# Import users through xml in openfire admin console

Tags: openfire

I have Openfire 3.6.3 installed on my server.

When it try to import users through admin panel its generating an error

**The import file does not match the user schema.**

My sample file is import.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
  <Openfire>
   <User>
     <Username>xxxx</Username> 
     <Password>****</Password> 
     <Email>xxxx@myserver</Email> 
     <Name>aaa</Name> 
     <CreationDate>1241507639546</CreationDate> 
      <ModifiedDate>1241507639546</ModifiedDate> 
   <Roster>
   <Item jid="user@gmail.com" askstatus="-1" recvstatus="-1" substatus="2" name="user">
    <Group /> 
    </Item>
    </Roster>
    </User>
    </Openfire>
```

Please help me

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a user in the OpenFire admin console. Export the user list, then compare the resulting XML with the one that you have.

Here's a sample of how it *should* look:

```
<Openfire>
  <User>
    <Username>admin</Username>
    <Password>*****</Password>
    <Email>*****@gmail.com</Email>
    <Name>Administrator</Name>
    <CreationDate>1233673175062</CreationDate>
    <ModifiedDate>0</ModifiedDate>
    <Roster/>
  </User>
</Openfire>
```

I don't have the "roster" contents in my XML... Try removing it and then trying again.

EDIT

Your original post made no mention that you were trying to *modify* existing users, which is a totally different procedure.

Here's what I'd recommend:

1. Export your current users
2. Merge the two XML files. Any good file-diff utility should be able to do the trick.
3. Delete all the users in the main system.
4. Import the merged XML.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for replying but i don't want to create a new user i want to add an item to the existing user.


Please help

Comment: Hi, Thanks

I have created a user named test through admin panel(without any roster item).
Now, when i try to import xml file with username which i have created along with some item jid i am getting the error

The following users already exist in the system or have invalid username and were not loaded

Pls help

Comment: Hi, I just want to add some items to the roster of a particular user but not want to add new users.